# Asp.Net Mvc RouteData is filled with wrong parameters

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes

```
routes .Add ("Detail",
                new Route ("{maincategory}/{category}",
                          new RouteValueDictionary (new { controller = "Category", action = "Detail"}),
                          new RouteValueDictionary (new { category = new FromValuesListConstraint ("")}),
                          new MyRouteHandler ()));

        routes.Add("Category",
                new Route("{category}",
                          new RouteValueDictionary(new { controller = "Category", action = "Index", category = "" }),
                          new RouteValueDictionary(new { category = new FromValuesListConstraint("") }),
                          new MyRouteHandler()));

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default",                                              // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}",                           // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" }  // Parameter defaults

        );
```

My routes are like this. But when I run the website Home page is displayed .After Home page is displayed something happens and again a new new quest is made ( I don't know why)I override the MvcRouteHandler and place a breakpoint in it.

```
public class MyRouteHandler : MvcRouteHandler
{
    protected override IHttpHandler GetHttpHandler(RequestContext requestContext)
    {
        var url = HttpContext.Current.Request.RawUrl;
        var route = requestContext.RouteData;  
        return new MvcHandler(requestContext);
    }
}
```

url variable is /Content/Divider.gif. Because of that after the home page displayed the application gives error. I tried everything to understand the problem as a novice mvc user.But I couldn't find anything.

Thanks!

Comment: Could you please do a solution wide search for the term "Divider.gif" and see where you are using it? Is it in a master page, view?

Comment: divider.gif is in Css file. 
background: transparent url('divider.gif')
But there is not file in my solution like this. I am using an old css from my friends web site

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the file /Content/Divider.gif exist on your website?

It's likely that it is trying to execute it as a route because the file does not exist and that is the source of your problem.